# Measurement units - advanced digitizing toolbar - QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I want to create a polygon with certain dimensions in QGIS. 180x180 feet.

I am trying to use advanced digitizing toolbar in order to create it. But I do not know the measurement units of d (distance) value. I am using EPSG: 3857. d values are not measured in units for sure, as I tried to create a polygon 100 m x 100 m by setting d = 100 and the dimensions of the generated poly are not 100m x 100m. Do you know how I can set or at least identify the measurements units of d?

Comment: Don't trust 3857 for *anything* involving distance -- Web Mercator is notoriously inaccurate for distance measurement; just look at Greenland and South America.

Comment: Thank you Vince, you saved me from a lot of trouble

Comment: Use an equal-distance projection, or a local projection.